# How to Implement Adsterra in next.js / react.js project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, ads

So I am trying to implement Adsterra Banner 300x50 on a ts/js reactjs + nextjs project, This is Adsterra provided script code for me to implement in the website:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
atOptions = {
    'key' : 'XXXXXX',
    'format' : 'iframe',
    'height' : 50,
    'width' : 320,
    'params' : {}
};
document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http' + (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 's' : '') + '://www.effectivecreativeformat.com/66e709b141fa8aa6d66cfda7e0b098a6/invoke.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
</script>
```

And this is how I implement it, using 'Script/next'

```html
<Script id="show-banner" strategy="afterInteractive">
{`
atOptions = {
    'key' : 'XXXXXX',
    'format' : 'iframe',
    'height' : 50,
    'width' : 320,
    'params' : {}
};
document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http' + (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 's' : '') + '://www.effectivecreativeformat.com/66e709b141fa8aa6d66cfda7e0b098a6/invoke.js"></scr'+'ipt>');
`}
</Script>
```

The problem I encounter here is, once the page load, everything got blank and white only. I hope someone can help me with experience in impementing Adsterra on a nextjs or react projects. thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this is how I make it work

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
export default function Banner(): JSX.Element {
    const banner = useRef<HTMLDivElement>()

    const atOptions = {
        key: 'KEY_HERE',
        format: 'iframe',
        height: 50,
        width: 320,
        params: {},
    }
    useEffect(() => {
    if (banner.current && !banner.current.firstChild) {
        const conf = document.createElement('script')
        const script = document.createElement('script')
        script.type = 'text/javascript'
        script.src = `//www.highperformancedformats.com/${atOptions.key}/invoke.js`
        conf.innerHTML = `atOptions = ${JSON.stringify(atOptions)}`

        banner.current.append(conf)
        banner.current.append(script)
    }
}, [banner])

    return <div className="mx-2 my-5 border border-gray-200 justify-center items-center text-white text-center" ref={banner}></div>
}
```

Comment: Hey, this is a good solution. However `!banner.current` could be undefined initially hence `!banner.current.firstChild` will fail. I have updated the answer to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

**Code for react js**

```
 import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export default function AdBanner() {
    const banner = useRef();
    const atOptions = {
        key: 'Inert your add key here',
        format: 'iframe',
        height: 250,
        width: 320,
        params: {},
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (banner.current && !banner.current.firstChild) {
            const conf = document.createElement('script');
            const script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = `//www.topcreativeformat.com/${atOptions.key}/invoke.js`;
            conf.innerHTML = `atOptions = ${JSON.stringify(atOptions)}`;

            banner.current.append(conf);
            banner.current.append(script);
        }
    }, [banner]);

    return <div className="mx-2 my-5 border border-gray-200 justify-center items-center text-white text-center" ref={banner}></div>;
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you found the code helpful! I noticed your code is quite similar. It would be great if you could acknowledge that your solution is based on the code I provided earlier.

Answer (score -1):

Mathew Agustin Bella's answer is perfect for React,
I want to answer this for anyone who has this issue with Angular

in your component.ts file

```
export class adComponent{

@ViewChild('adDiv') adDiv!: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement> | undefined;

atOptions = {
        'key' : ''KEY_HERE'',
        'format' : 'iframe',
        'height' : 90,
        'width' : 728,
        'params' : {}
    };

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log("adsloading")
    const conf = document.createElement('script')
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = "//www.profitablecreativeformat.com/${atOptions.key}/invoke.js";
    conf.innerHTML = `atOptions = ${JSON.stringify(this.atOptions)}`;
    this.adDiv?.nativeElement.append(conf);
    this.adDiv?.nativeElement.append(s);
  }
}
```

and in your component.html file

```
<div #adDiv>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! However, the post is specifically about React.js and TypeScript, not Angular. If you have insights or answers related to React.js and TypeScript, that would be greatly appreciated. Let's try to stay on topic to ensure the discussion is relevant to the original post.